# JavaFx animating a path with a shape

Tags: javafx, path, graphicscontext

I am working on a project with a feature of animating a path with a line. So when I press a button, a line goes through all the circles in the canvas. But I see that there is a slight difference in my path and the strokeline. It doesnt go through the circles. Please kindly advice thank you. 
This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PathVisualization extends Application {

private static double SCENE_WIDTH = 1000;
private static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 500;

private Canvas canvas;
private GraphicsContext gc;
private Button clear; 
private Animation animation;
private ArrayList<Circle> num;

 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setMaxSize(800,500);
   // path = new Path();
    canvas = new Canvas(SCENE_WIDTH,SCENE_HEIGHT);

    TextField no = new TextField();
    Button add = new Button("Add Circle");
    Button playAnimation = new Button("Play");
    clear = new Button("Clear");
    Button pause = new Button("Pause");

    VBox control = new VBox();
    control.getChildren().add(no);
    control.getChildren().add(add);
    control.getChildren().add(playAnimation);
    control.getChildren().add(clear);
    control.getChildren().add(pause);


    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    bp.setCenter(root);
    bp.setLeft(control);

    num = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    clear.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
        num.clear();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, gc.getCanvas().getWidth(), gc.getCanvas().getHeight());
        root.getChildren().clear();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    });

    add.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
        int cirNum = Integer.parseInt(no.getText());
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int j=0;j<cirNum;j++) {
            int x = rand.nextInt((int)root.getMaxWidth()-1);
            int y = rand.nextInt((int)root.getMaxHeight()-1);
            Circle circle = new Circle(x,y,10);
            num.add(circle);
            root.getChildren().add(circle);
        }

        //Heuristic Change
        Path path = new Path();
        path.setStroke(Color.RED);
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(num.get(0).getCenterX(),num.get(0).getCenterY()));
        path.setStrokeWidth(1);

        for (int i=0;i<num.size();i++) {
            try {
                path.getElements().addAll(new LineTo(num.get(i).getCenterX(),num.get(i).getCenterY()));
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                path.getElements().addAll(new LineTo(num.get(0).getCenterX(),num.get(0).getCenterY()));
            }
        }


        root.getChildren().addAll(path);

        //create animation
        animation = createPathAnimation(path, Duration.seconds(num.size()/4));

    });

     playAnimation.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
          animation.play();
    });

     pause.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
         animation.pause();
     });


    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bp, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT));
    primaryStage.show();

}



private Animation createPathAnimation(Path path, Duration duration) {

    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    // move a node along a path. we want its position
    Circle pen = new Circle(0,0,0);
    // create path transition
    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition(duration, path, pen);
    pathTransition.currentTimeProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Duration>() {

      Location oldLocation = null;

        /**
         * Draw a line from the old location to the new location
         */
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {

            // skip starting at 0/0
            if( oldValue == Duration.ZERO)
                return;

            // get current location

            double x = pen.getTranslateX();
            double y = pen.getTranslateY();



         // initialize the location
            if( oldLocation == null) {
                oldLocation = new Location();
                oldLocation.x = x;
                oldLocation.y = y;
                return;
            }

            // draw line
            gc.setStroke(Color.GREENYELLOW);

            gc.setLineWidth(5);

            gc.strokeLine(oldLocation.x, oldLocation.y, x, y);


            // update old location with current one
            oldLocation.x = x;
            oldLocation.y = y;

        }
    });

    pathTransition.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);  
    return pathTransition;
}

public static class Location {
    double x;
    double y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This is the issue. At certain corners, the strokeline does not go through the circle and makes a weird cut.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPTZo.png)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Does it happen consistently or frequently on your side?

Comment: not consistently, but happens often to notice it. It is too obvious on a big screen.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce it originally, but after more tries I managed to reproduce it. It looks like this is due to latency.

As far as I know (I'm not an expert in animations), animations (including `PathTransition`) use a timer internally, and each tick is generally equivalent to JavaFX scene graph pulse duration. This means that animations are updated at 60 times per second maximum. When a pulse happens, the `PathTransition` calculates the new translate values based on the elapsed time on the timer. So what happens here is that the calculated translate values are quite far apart between two particular pulses. In general, the more things you try to do on the JavaFX Application Thread, the more likely this would happen.

If you are trying to draw a tracing line based on the animation, there is no way you could avoid this latency. However, you could avoid the problem of the drawn path cutting corners, by breaking it up into multiple animations. Each animation would move in a straight line, and each of your tracing line is guaranteed to start from the start and end at the ending point.

I tried this and it works:

```
// Heuristic Change
// Path path = new Path();
// path.setStroke(Color.RED);
// path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(num.get(0).getCenterX(), num.get(0).getCenterY()));
// path.setStrokeWidth(1);

// for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
// try {
// path.getElements().addAll(new LineTo(num.get(i).getCenterX(), num.get(i).getCenterY()));
// }
// catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
// path.getElements().addAll(new LineTo(num.get(0).getCenterX(), num.get(0).getCenterY()));
// }
// }

List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < num.size() - 1; i++) {
    Circle current = num.get(i);
    Circle next = num.get(i + 1);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setStroke(Color.RED);
    path.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(current.getCenterX(), current.getCenterY()),
            new LineTo(next.getCenterX(), next.getCenterY()));
    path.setStrokeWidth(1);

    paths.add(path);
}

// root.getChildren().addAll(path);

root.getChildren().addAll(paths);

Circle pen = new Circle();

// create animation
// animation = createPathAnimation(path, Duration.seconds(num.size()/4));
animation = createPathAnimation(paths, Duration.millis(200), pen);
```

And...

```
private Animation createPathAnimation(List<Path> paths, Duration duration, Circle pen) {
    SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition();

    // ...

    for (Path path : paths) {
        // The same PathTransition stuff you had

        seq.getChildren().add(pathTransition);
    }

    return seq;
}
```

The only thing that changed is that the speed changes at each segment of the full path. If you want to keep that constant, you have to apply Pythagoras' theorem to find the distance, and adjust the duration accordingly.